# How to resolve Undefined variable models error, in Python-Django Framework

Tags: python, django

Following is the code in views.py

```
class CreateGroup(LoginRequiredMixin,generic.CreateView):
    fields = ('name','description')
    model = Group

class SingleGroup(generic.DetailView):
    model = Group


class ListGroups(generic.ListView):
     model = Group


class JoinGroup(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.RedirectView):

    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return reverse("groups:single",kwargs={"slug": self.kwargs.get("slug")})

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        group = get_object_or_404(Group,slug=self.kwargs.get("slug"))

        try:
            GroupMember.objects.create(user=self.request.user,group=group)

        except IntegrityError:
            messages.warning(self.request,("Warning, already a member of 
                                           {}".format(group.name)))

        else:
            messages.success(self.request,"You are now a member of the {} 
                                             group.".format(group.name))

        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)


class LeaveGroup(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.RedirectView):

    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return reverse("groups:single",kwargs={"slug": self.kwargs.get("slug")})

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        try:

            membership = models.GroupMember.objects.filter(
                user=self.request.user,
                group__slug=self.kwargs.get("slug")
            ).get()

        except models.GroupMember.ObjectDoesNotExist:

            messages.warning(self.request,
                "You can't leave this group because you aren't in it."
            )
        else:
            membership.delete()
            messages.success(
                self.request,
                "You have successfully left this group."
            )
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

I am developing a social media clone site using Django. I had created the views for implying Groups and Group Members, and their membership.

### It gives the error as: Undefined variable 'models' 'GroupMember' has no 'objects' member

Comment: post the model groupmember

Comment: import your models in `views.py` from where it is...just like `from path.where.it.belongs import models`

Comment: Guess into the blue: you forgot to inherit from `models.Model`.

Comment: I tried importing the models and it resolved the error of undefined variable 'models'.

Comment: Could you please elaborate regarding resolving the other error?